# I want to return object with timestramp and count

Tags: json, python-3.x, datetime

#### I have list which contains multiple similar timestamps i have count their occurrences like below code :

```
count = collections.Counter(MyList)
return [{"result": count}]
```

#### It gives me result like this :

```
"2021-10-09T00:26:16": 10,
"2021-10-08T15:08:37": 5,
"2021-10-08T13:40:50": 6,
```

## But I want a result like this

```
{"timestamp": "2021-01-01T00:00:00", "count": 10},
{"timestamp": "2021-01-02T00:00:00", "count": 5},
{"timestamp": "2021-01-03T00:00:00", "count": 6},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dictionary Comprehension to meet the requirement.

```
count = collections.Counter(MyList)
result = [{'timestamp': k, 'count': v}  for k,v in count.items()]
```

Learn more about Dictionary Comprehension from [PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).